# SQL Query for a MarketingCloud campaign opens?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, automation, sql

I'm trying to create an automation that looks back at a specific campaign and sets a flag on their profile if the user opened the email. This campaign would run every day and then talk back to Salesforce with that field.

However, I can't find information on selecting specific MarketingCloud data point such as an email campaign for querying purposes. Anyone familiar with implementing a similar project?

Answer (score 2):

There’s no data views available for Campaigns in SFMC, a workaround is to use Send Logging. Adding a field like CampaignID to the sendable data extension will allow you to link your campaign to data views like _Sent, _Open, _Click, etc.

The names of the columns or fields in the send logging data extension and the sendable data extension must match exactly to log any values. Send logging is not enabled by default, you will need to contact support to have it enabled in your account.

Below are some links to the Salesforce documentation explaining in more detail. Hope this helps!

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_logging.htm&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000233298&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Answer (score 0):

Before you read further it may seem difficult to create a home-grown solution to send email results back to Sales Cloud because **the Marketing Cloud Connector is supposed to serve this purpose**. It sends individual email results back to Sales Cloud and they are associated with each contact. I think that might actually suit your needs better than trying to create something from scratch. If you know this option won't work for you, read on:

Are you looking to query general data views in Marketing Cloud? They're organized as follows:

_Job: A Job is an email that takes place in a specific point in time. When you hit "Send" or schedule an email, a Job is created.

_Sent: Every email that a job sends gets logged here as an item in _Sent.

_Open: Every time a tracked email is opened it gets logged here.

My guess is that if you're looking to write a query to look for open data from a specific email campaign, you'd want to look in the _Open data extension for emails that match a specific date or job.